# How to write to a CSV file with a column which have blank row

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTDGU.png)    file.csv =[
{
"First Name": "Kieran",
"Last Name": "Wilson",
"Age (Years)": "89",
"Sex": "Male",
"Retired": "True",
"Marital Status": "married or civil partner",
"Dependants": "3"
},
{
"First Name": "Ryan",
"Last Name": "Clarke",
"Age (Years)": "23",
"Sex": "Male",
"Retired": "False",
"Marital Status": "married or civil partner",
"Dependants": " "
},
{
"First Name": "Clive",
"Last Name": "Evans",
"Age (Years)": "67",
"Sex": "Male",
"Retired": "True",
"Marital Status": "single",
"Dependants": " "
} ]

```
with open("file.csv",mode='a') as myfile:
     myfile=csv.writer(myfile,delimiter=",")
     for line_number,line in enumerate(myfile):
           if line[10] == "":
               myfile.writerow("N/A")
     print(my_file)
```

note this is actually a larger dataset, the original header of "dependants" CSV file is in line[10] and the columns have some blank rows, i want the blank rows to be replaced with "N/A"

Comment: That's not a CSV file, it's JSON.

Comment: `enumerate(myfile)` won't return anything. You can't read from a file opened in append mode.

Comment: Can you give an example of desired output?

Comment: The variable name is also invalid - are you sure you ran the code provided?

Answer (score 0):

What you have there isnt a csv but a JSON file. If you want to write it in a file then you could do:

1. replace blanks with "N/A"
2. get the str property and write it to file.

note that i will use as namevar filecvs all together.

1.

```
for aDict in filecsv:
    for key,val in aDict.items():
        if val== " ":
            aDict[key] = "N/A"
```

2. 

```
with open("file.csv",mode='a') as myfile:
         myfile.write(filecsv.__str__())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is a list of dictionaries, you would be better off using `csv.DictWriter` than `csv.Writer`. And rather than intercepting invalid values in the middle of writing the file, it will be simpler to fix the data beforehand. There are a couple of other issues with the code, most importantly the fact that `line` in the loop is a dictionary, but you are accessing it by index as if it were a list.

And as one of the comments points out, calling a variable `file.csv` is a syntax error unless you have defined some object called `file`.

Start by creating the dictionary with a workable name:

```
file_csv =[ { "First Name": "Kieran", "Last Name": "Wilson", "Age (Years)": "89", "Sex": "Male", "Retired": "True", "Marital Status": "married or civil partner", "Dependants": "3" }, { "First Name": "Ryan", "Last Name": "Clarke", "Age (Years)": "23", "Sex": "Male", "Retired": "False", "Marital Status": "married or civil partner", "Dependants": " " }, { "First Name": "Clive", "Last Name": "Evans", "Age (Years)": "67", "Sex": "Male", "Retired": "True", "Marital Status": "single", "Dependants": " " } ]
```

Then fix up the blank columns to contain `N/A`:

```
for row in file_csv:
    for k,v in row.items():
        if v == " ":
            row[k]="N/A")
```

This will deal with all columns that might contain a blank and with more data you might find that happening.

Your code uses `myfile` for both the file and the `csv.Writer` object. That is a bad idea. And unless you know you are appending to an existing file, use `w` not `a`.

```
with open("file.csv",mode="w") as myfile:
    mywriter = csv.DictWriter(myfile,delimiter=",",fieldnames=file_csv[0].keys())
    mywriter.writeheader()
    mywriter.writerows(file_csv)
```